# Component updated state not being reflected in hashchange handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, hashchange

I've created a `useRouterDisclosure` hook to use with modals of my application, where whenever I've to open a modal I push it's key to the hash of the url and to close it, I can simply remove the hash. Doing it this way also handles, back button modal closing on mobile devices and in desktop browsers.

Code:

```js
function useRouterDisclosure({ name, Modal }) {
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
    const modalQueryKey = `${encodeURIComponent(name)}-modal-state`;

    const onToggle = () => {
        if (!isOpen) {
            window.location.hash = modalQueryKey;
        } else {
            window.history.back();
        }
    };

    const hashChangeHandler = () => {
        const hash = window.location.hash;
        const hashVal = hash.length ? hash.split('#')[1] : '';
        console.log('hash handler: ', isOpen, name);

        if (!isOpen && hashVal === modalQueryKey) {
            console.log('opening: ', name);
            onOpen();
        }

        if (isOpen && hashVal !== modalQueryKey) {
            console.log('closing: ', name);
            onClose();
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashChangeHandler);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('hashchange', hashChangeHandler);
        }
    }, []);

    const Component = (props) => (
        !!isOpen && <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onToggle} {...props} />
    );


    return [onToggle, Component];
};
```

Due to some reason, the updated value of `isOpen` is not reflected in `hashChangeHandler` and hence the modal never closes because `isOpen` is always false. What could be the possible reasons for it and how to handle it?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [why updated state not reflected inside an event listener: React Native, Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772776/why-updated-state-not-reflected-inside-an-event-listener-react-native-hooks)? Basically, you need to add `isOpen` to the `useEffect`'s dependencies array.